# how to show response message in alert?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, uialertview

I want to show response message as alert message. My code is given below

```
parameters["FName"] = txtFirstName.text ?? ""
parameters["LName"] = txtLastName.text ?? ""
parameters["Email"] = txtEmailId.text ?? ""
parameters["Mobile"] = txtMobileNumber.text ?? ""
parameters["Password"] = txtPassword.text ?? ""
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            (response) in
            print(response.result.value!)
        }
```

And my response message is...

```
{
    message = "Registered Successfully!";
    result = True;
}
```

I want to show the value of "message" key. please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if let result = response.result.value,  let JSON = result as! [String: Any] {

print(JSON["message"]as? String)

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "congrats", message: JSON["message"]as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)

     }
```

or use  [this](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSMessages) library for advance notification message

```
self.showMessage(JSON["message"]as? String, type: .success) //.success mean green color alert
```

Comment: the response is [String: String]--> dict,  not a string

Comment: you want to fetch message from response ?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake never i see the json response; key and value separate using equal to

Comment: yes i want fetch value of message key from response

Comment: it's json response ?

Comment: @gowtham - is the response is [String: String] or [String: Any]

Comment: maybe it's become a good solution because now the error handled

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : String]'

Comment: greet gose to @Anbu.karthik

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have a one question in socket could you please help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207652/swift-ios-application-does-not-connect-to-server-using-socket-io?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

```
if let responseDict = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let msg = responseDict["message"] as? String  {


         //show alert here....

}
```